# Ejecutar Macro desde una consulta (MS ACCESS 2013)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2007

¿Es posible ejecutar una macro a partir de una consulta en ACCESS 2013?

Necesito que se ejecute sólo haciendo click a la consulta, no sé si esto es posible con  clausulas como PROCEDURE, EXECUTE...

-

.

Asistiendo a la sugerencia de llamar la macro con una función que a su vez llame a un Sub, intente lo siguiente

```
Function funcion1() 

Call proc1 

End Function
```

---

```
Sub proc1()

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Consulta1", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "consulta1"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Consulta2", acViewNormal, acReadOnly


End Sub
```

---

Cada uno funciona perfectamente cuando los ejecuto desde VBA, pero intenté llamarlos desde la consulta con

```
SELECT funcion1()
```

Pero marca un error '2486' esta accion no se puede ejecutar ahora

Ahora mi principal pregunta a la sugerencia es: ¿es `Select` la forma correcta de llamar a la función desde la ventana SQL? ¿O qué cláusula debo usar?

Answer (score 1):

Sí se puede, aunque en un par de pasos.

De primeras, no, no puedes llamar a un procedimiento Sub desde una consulta. Pero sin embargo, sí puedes llamar a una UDF que a su vez llame al Sub.

> Para ejecutar un procedimiento Sub o procedimiento de evento escrito
>   en Visual Basic, cree un procedimiento Function que llame al
>   procedimiento Sub o un procedimiento de evento. A continuación, use la
>   acción de macro EjecutarCódigo para ejecutar el procedimiento de la
>   función.

Tienes toda la información en [Acción de macro EjecutarCódigo](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/acci%c3%b3n-de-macro-ejecutarc%c3%b3digo-e6a62d3f-02c6-4daf-a5f7-402fd600bed4?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Pongo un ejemplo sencillo. Por un lado, yo tengo en un módulo el Sub que quiero ejecutar. El mío simplemente hace un Msgbox.

```
Sub SALUDAR()
Debug.Print "Hola" 'Escribe Hola en la ventana Inmediato
End Sub
```

También tengo definida la función. Mi UDF simplemente llama al sub anterior:

```
Function LLAMAR_A_SUB()
Call SALUDAR
End Function
```

Luego, mi consulta es así (la he llamado Consulta1)

```
SELECT LLAMAR_A_SUB() AS Expr1;
```

Y por último, he replicado tu manera de abrir las consultas desde VBA.

```
Sub PRUEBAS()

Application.DoCmd.OpenQuery "Consulta1"
Application.DoCmd.Close acQuery, "consulta1", acSaveNo

End Sub
```

Si ejecuto el Sub pruebas, primero abre la Consulta1, pero esta consulta tiene un campo calculado que llama a la función LLAMAR A SUB, y cuando se ejecuta la función, entonces se ejecuta el Sub Saludar. Y verás que en la ventana inmediato te sale la palabra Hola.

Comment: Hola, gracias por lo que comentas, pero ¿ para  llamar la función en la ventana sql debo usar la clausula SELECT?

Como, SELECT funcion1(), porque me devuelve un error, ya que creo que select solo devuelve tablas, puse los detalles editados en mi pregunta, gracias nuevamente

Comment: @EnriqueSalazar He actualizado mi respuesta. Mira la explicación, pero creo que tu error está en que deberías poner `SELECT funcion1() AS Expr1`, siendo `Expr1` un nombre personalizado para el campo calculado.